# Why does scrolling raise a Selenium webdriver exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am writing a bot that presses request buttons.

I scroll to the request button finding it by id and click it.

I am using Safari and Python 3.

```
#pop_up_request_buttons_id_list - all of the ids

button = driver.find_element_by_id(pop_up_request_buttons_id_list[2])
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", button)

print(pop_up_request_buttons_id_list[2])
button.click()
```

for some reason this raises a Selenium webdriver exception with no message.

Notes:

Scrolling to the button's parent class does not raise an exception and the button gets clicked. Also I would like to note that if I scroll to the parent class only one button is visible but when I scroll by id 2 buttons are visible on screen after scrolling.

Why is the exception raised and why doesn't the button get clicked?

Comment: What exception is raising?

Comment: The message is empty. It just says selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException

Comment: Please add the Selenium and Safari version. You shall test that behavior with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make it reproducible. You may create a simple HTML snippet with large height requiring scrolling. Make your automation code also complete (driver instantiation). Note, that, beside Javascript, there's also [`move_to_element()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains).

Comment: can you try this  : driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", button)

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of *Selenium webdriver exception with no message* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *visibility of element located* and you can use the following solution:

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "pop_up_request_buttons_id_list[2]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", button)
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```